# Взять строку с удалением PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите, как взять строку с БД MYSQL.
Потом положить ее в переменную, затем удалить.

Язык программирования - PHP
Движок  - DLE
Для примера нужно взять контент статьи.

Answer (score 0):

взять из БД

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'ваша таблица'") or die(mysql_error());
```

создание ассоциативного массива

```
$massiv = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Взять id первой строки и положить в переменную `$idpost`

```
$idpost = $massiv[id];
```

Взять текст с массива

```
$content = $massiv[full_story];
```

удалить строку по ID

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM 'таблица' WHERE 'строка' = '$idpost'");
```

Вот так должно работать.

Comment: Таких функций `mysql_*` уже нет в php :P

Comment: Переставила кавычки на такие  - ` и все заработало.

Comment: Таких функций mysql_* уже нет в php :P - куда же они делись?

Comment: Читайте предупреждения в документации http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Вроде как и ответ верный, но выбирать решением не стоит. Лучше всё таки на PDO или MySQLi переписать.